# range of $3x^2-2xy$ subjected to $x^2+y^2=1$

Tags: inequality

If $x^2+y^2=1$. then the range of expression $3x^2-2xy$ without trigonometric substitution method

what i have done  try here is  use arithmetic geometric inequality

$\displaystyle x^2+y^2\geq 2xy$

$\displaystyle -2xy\geq -(x^2+y^2)$

$\displaystyle 3x^2-2xy\geq 2x^2-y^2$

this will not help more

how do i solve it help  me please

Comment: Maybe put $x=\cos t, y=\sin t$ and plug these into objective function, then constraint automatic and need to get range of resulting trig function.

Comment: "without trigonometric substitution"

Answer (score 2):

If you have the requisite linear algebra theorems at your disposal, then you can recognize

$$3x^2-2xy=\pmatrix{x&y}\pmatrix{3&-1\\-1&0}\pmatrix{x\\y}$$

where the $2\times2$ matrix is selfadjoint with eigenvalues satisfying $\lambda^2-3\lambda-1=0$.  For selfadjoint matrices $M$, the corresponding eigenvectors are orthogonal, and thus when the vector $\mathbf{x}$ ranges over the unit ball (in this case the unit circle), $\mathbf{x}^TM\mathbf{x}$ ranges from the *smallest* eigenvalue to the *largest*, in this case, from $(3-\sqrt{13})/2$ to $(3+\sqrt{13})/2$.

Answer (score 1):

$3 x^2 - 2 x y$ with $y = \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$ is $3 x^2 \pm 2 x \sqrt{1 - x^2}:$

[image]

Take derivative w.r.t. $x$, set it to zero and solve.

Note that the two functions are reflections about $x=0$, so their ranges are the same.

Comment: Note $y$ could also be the negative of what you have.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, the two functions are reflections of each other about $y$ axis and have the same range

Answer (score 1):

Since $x^2+y^2=1$, you can substitute for $y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ in $f(x,y)=3x^2-2xy$ to get $g(x)=f(x,\pm\sqrt{1-x^2})=3x^2\pm2x\sqrt{1-x^2},-1\le x\le1$ and find the extrema using standard techniques.

Answer (score 1):

The range that you're after is $\left[\frac{3-\sqrt{13}}2,\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}2\right]$. In fact, if $x^2+y^2=1$, then$$3x^2-2xy=3x^2\pm x\sqrt{1-x^2}.$$So, for each $x\in[-1,1]$, let$$f(x)=3x^2-2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\text{ and let }g(x)=3x^2+x\sqrt{1-x^2}.$$Now, using that standard Calculus techniques, you can check that the range of both functions $f$ and $g$ is $\left[\frac{3-\sqrt{13}}2,\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}2\right]$.

Answer (score 1):

For a calculs-free approach, note that
$$
\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2}\left[\frac{2y-(3+\sqrt{13})x}{\sqrt{26+6\sqrt{13}}}\right]^2+\frac{3-\sqrt{13}}{2}\left[\frac{2y-(3-\sqrt{13})x}{\sqrt{26-6\sqrt{13}}}\right]^2=3x^2-2xy
$$
and
$$
\left[\frac{2y-(3+\sqrt{13})x}{\sqrt{26+6\sqrt{13}}}\right]^2+\left[\frac{2y-(3-\sqrt{13})x}{\sqrt{26-6\sqrt{13}}}\right]^2=x^2+y^2
$$
So the range of $3x^2-2xy$, as $(x,y)$ varies on the unit circle, is the closed interval with endpoints $\dfrac{3\pm\sqrt{13}}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Making $y = \lambda x$ and substituting we have

$$
\mbox{Variation for}\ \ \  x^2(3-2\lambda)\ \ \ \mbox{s. t. }\ \ x^2(1+\lambda^2) = 1
$$

or variation for

$$
f(\lambda) = \frac{3-2\lambda}{1+\lambda^2}
$$

now determining the stationary points with $f'(\lambda) = 0$ obtaining

$$
\lambda = \frac 12\left(3\pm\sqrt{13}\right)
$$

etc.